# Regex to match nested show path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match a show path of a nested resource. The path goes like this: `/users/:user_id/products/:id` - I have been unable to write a regex to check if a url is for this path. I don't want anything after the products/:id to pass the match. Right now I have the following:

```
/users/([^&]*)/products/
```

This works in that it'll match the url path I'm looking for, but I cant figure out how to end it after the /products/:id so it won't match actions such as /edit. So `users/1-my-name-is-bob/products/1-awesome-product` should match, but `users/1-my-name-is-bob/products/1-awesome-product/edit` should not match the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this pattern:

```
\/users\/([^&\/]+)\/products\/[^\/]+\Z
```

`\Z` stand for end-of-the-string

you can remove slashes at the begining if not needed, or make it optional with a question mark